# ffmpeg overlay an gif over video to full scale of video dimension

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay

I would like to add a transparent gif image over a video, I can do it using the following command

```
ffmpeg -i inputVideo.mp4 -i yourImage.png -filter_complex "overlay=5:5" -codec:a copy outputVideo.mp4
```

But what I want to do is that overlay image would full dimension of the video ,where the video dimension is unknown, for example

[image]

For example the above image would be applied to full screen of the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
f="input 1.mp4"
WID="$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=width -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$f")"
HEI="$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=height -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$f")"
echo $WID x $HEI
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$f" -ignore_loop 0 -i "L6h34.gif" -filter_complex [1:0]scale="${WID}"-10:"${HEI}"-10[v0],[0:0][v0]overlay=5:5:shortest=1[v] -map [v] -c:v h264_nvenc -f matroska -y "/mnt/sklad/tmp/L6h34.mkv"
```

scale gif

Answer (score 1):

Use the [scale2ref](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref) and [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i input.gif -filter_complex "[0][1]scale2ref[b][f];[b][f]overlay=shortest=1" -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```